# Recover a file after shred command

Tags: bash, rm, forensics, shred

Let's say I have some sensitive files in my computer and I want to completely delete them so that no one can ever retrieve them.
For that, I can use the `rm` command, but it's still easily recoverable. So I choose to use the `shred` command that will overwrite my file with noise and then delete it.

```bash
> shred -n 120 -u my_file.txt
```

However, I'm still not sure my method is completely safe.
What can be done in order to recover my file after I shred it ?

#### Prerequisite

let's say I have access to every forensic software available and lab equipment to recover my data.
Let's also say I want to preserve the physical integrity of my hard drive (so no microwave, fire, or any physical damage).

#### Research

I also tried :

```bash
dd if=/dev/zero of=my_file.txt bs=16M status=progress
```

In order to replace the content of my file with 0s. But I don't know if this method is better than `shred.`

Comment: "However, I'm still not sure my method is completely safe." – This is un-answerable without a precise, accurate, objectively-measurable definition of what, *exactly* you mean by "safe". "Safe" is always relative to a threat model: what is it that you are protecting? Who is the attacker (i.e. who are you protecting against)? How much is what you are protecting worth to you? How much is it worth to your attacker? How long is what you are protecting valuable? How much are you willing to spend protecting it? How much is your attacker willing to spend getting their hands on it? What are the …

Comment: … possible attack vectors? I.e. if you don't have a bodyguard, then there is no point spending thousands of dollars protecting your data if the attacker can just beat the answers out of you with a $5 piece of steel pipe.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/538

If someone is going to put in the effort to reverse a `shred` command, they'll try beating you with a wrench first. Honestly, if you're that important, you won't be asking questions on SE, have a cell phone, or use the internet at all (e.g.: Snowden).

Comment: To answer all above comments, this question is for research purpose. No one is trying to attack me, I'm just curious about forensics in general and I wonder how to fully erase data on a SSD.

Comment: Related questions: https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=shred+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @Vincent There are conspiracy theories floating around that there may be some SSDs which offer a disk erase operation but for some reason or another fail in actually performing the operation as expected while still reporting "ok, done." - And now we're entering the con-spiral, because one cannot prove that e.g. the drive's controller actually fully erased the encryption key and did not internally keep a secret copy for later retrieval by some super-powerful, super-secret entity highly interested in the that video of your toddler's first steps...

Comment: @JimmyB, hang out on the Linux kernel disk mailing lists long enough, and you'll find reports of drives misbehaving in any way you can imagine, and many ways you can't.  There are, in fact, SSDs out there that claim to support the "secure erase" command, but don't actually do anything.  This isn't because of any grand conspiracy, but simply because doing it this way was the cheapest way to add "supports secure erase" to the feature list.

Answer (score 18):

> *I'm still not sure my method is completely safe.*

It isn't:

> Shred basically relies on a very important assumption: that the file system overwrites data in place. This is the traditional way to do things, but many modern file system designs do not satisfy this assumption

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656146/how-to-use-the-shred-command-the-right-way#comment1234353_656147, comment by [Daniel Kelley](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/478694/daniel-kelley)

> The only way to make recovering of your sensitive data nearly impossible is to overwrite (“wipe” or “shred”) the data with several defined patterns.
>
> CAUTION: The use of wiping or shredding tools relies on a very important assumption: that the filesystem overwrites the data in place. This is the traditional way to do things, but many modern filesystem designs do not satisfy this assumption for example Ext4, XFS, ReiserFS, etc.

Source: [SystemRescue - Secure Deletion of Data](https://www.system-rescue.org/manual/Secure_Deletion_of_Data/)

Shred does not work on SSDs:

> Writing a block to an SSD does not overwrite the old block. That's because all recent SSDs use something called "wear levelling".
>
> To write a block to an SSD, you need to erase it first, and then you
> can write the new data. But erasing is an operation that can only be
> executed a limited number of times; each time you do an erase, you
> "weaken" the hardware, until the block cannot be properly erased
> any more.
>
> So instead of erasing and overwriting the same block, wear levelling
> will make the SSD pick a different, unused block, and will write to
> this block, leaving the data on the old block in place.
>
> And if the data on the old block is in place, that means it still can
> be read.
>
> So any of the commands you can use to "overwrite" a file (cp, dd, cat,
> shred, and many more) have this weakness: It does not actually
> overwrite the file at all, instead it writes zeroes, random data or
> whatever to new blocks.
>
> So unlike for HDs, this is not a good way to make sure your data is
> gone, and cannot be read by someone else.

Source: [Is shred bad for erasing SSDs? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593181/is-shred-bad-for-erasing-ssds), answer by [dirkt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/193028/dirkt)

---

Further Reading:

- [destruction - Security of linux shred utility - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62824/security-of-linux-shred-utility)

Comment: thank you for all this information. Does that mean that "erasing" data on an SSD is possible only if I fill this SSD with other data until there's no other new blocks that it has to write on the one I try to delete ? I don't know if I'm clear, but since SSD have limited storage, it shouldn't be able to write on "new" blocks indefinitely.

Comment: Many SSDs have a secure erase program ...

Comment: @Vincent writing to an SSD would waste write and erase cycles and due to the wear leveller would not guarantee all blocks were actually written. As David says many SSDs have programs that will erase the disk but in an operating system you could [TRIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)) the entire disk which would effectively tell the disk that every block is ready to be wiped and would cause the controller wear leveller to unlink all blocks and (eventually) erase them. The problem is that for some unknown time the data will remain in the actual flash chips.

Comment: The way around that is what is known as a SED or Self Encrypting Disk where there is only one block that needs to be earsed. That block contains the encryption keys and without those keys the data on disk is basically just random noise. The same can be achieved with bitlocker or other full disk encryption programs. What it boils down to is that deleting or `shred`ing files should never be considered a secure method of disposal. If you *must* protect your data then encryption and physical destruction are the only guaranteed methods for disposal.

Comment: i was going to chime in and say something about 'instead of shred you can use whole disk encryption' but someone i think beat me to it. i will just say that there are two types of whole disk encryption 'hardware' and 'software'. the 'hardware' version depends on the hardware implementation and so in many cases can not be trusted. for most people 'software' whole disk encryption is better because you can ensure it is implemented correctly.

Answer (score 7):

> Let's say I have some sensitive files in my computer and I want to
> completely delete them so that no one can ever retrieve them.

This in itself is a request that can never be satisfied. If we assume a conventional, magnetic drive then all research and literature I have ever read says it's impossible to recover meaningful data even after only a single pass of zeros.

Example: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221160815_Overwriting_Hard_Drive_Data_The_Great_Wiping_Controversy

> This study has demonstrated that correctly wiped data cannot
> reasonably be retrieved even if it is of a small size or found only
> over small parts of the hard drive. Not even with the use of a MFM or
> other known methods. The belief that a tool can be developed to
> retrieve gigabytes or terabytes of information from a wiped drive is
> in error.

**Can not be recovered, *now*!**

But one could still argue I didn't locate the correct research yet or although it may be true that this is the current state of affairs, it is not a guarantee that no one in the distant feature may be able to recover the data.

**Is overwrite/shred *in-place*?**

Since OP is discussing a single file, to overwrite the contents of the file (or shred or whatever you want to call it), we have to assume the file is overwritten in-place at file system level. So file is in clusters 10 - 20, shredder now gets to actually save the shredded file to clusters 10-20. If file system however decides to save to clusters 100 - 110 instead for whatever reason, the original file contents survive, the file system simply no longer points to it. In such an event the simplest of en user file recovery software can potentially recover the data you intended to overwrite/shred.

**Modern drives may not all do what you expect them to..**

Even IF we assume file system cooperates, a modern drive like and SSD or SMR drive will almost by definition write the shredded data to a *different physical location*. Added to that, modern drives may before writing the blocks to a 'final destination' cache the 'file', or better file data. For example many SMR drives reserve a CMR area for fast writes (Media Cache) where the data is written to, and later written to the slower SMR areas. Until the data in the CMR area is overwritten, 2 copies of your data exist.

The process for hybrid drives (SSHD) is similar.

**On an SSD even multiple copies of your file may exist ..**

SSD's are even worse than that due to the way data is organized, 'programmed' and erased. Due to characteristics of NAND, and how much can programmed at once (a page) and erased at once (an erase block) and that only an erased page can be programmed, it almost by definition never writes to the physical location you read from. IOW 'your shredder' reads file, scrambles the data and saves that. But the SSD will thus not overwrite the original data since the scrambled data is written somewhere else.

In addition, without you knowing, multiple copies of your file may exist as SSD's tend to shuffle data around all over the place (scrubbing, wear leveling and whatnot) with the intention to erase the stale copy at some point. *Researchers found upto 16 copies of a file* that was saved to SSD *only once*! Since only one copy is mapped to LBA, to to us, the end users it is as if only one copy of this data exists.

See: https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/fast11/tech/full_papers/Wei.pdf

> Figure 1: Multiple copies This graph shows The FTL duplicating files
> up to 16 times.

*So even if you succeeded in shredding your file in-place, many stale copies of the file may still exist, and may be recoverable with the right tools*!

**So, no your method is not safe.**

> However, I'm still not sure my method is completely safe. What can be
> done in order to recover my file after I shred it ?

After reading the previous, it should be obvious.

**All we need is a way to access this space in which these 'stale' copies of data still exist.**

Such modern drives typically work with a 'translator' or 'translation layer' (FTL) that maps LBA addresses to physical addresses, keeps track of status of page, wear, etc..

If an SSD saves your file, and even if file system writes to the exact same location, it finds an erased page to write the data to. The page the data was read from is not by definition. However for the OS it seems as if data was written the same range of LBA blocks. The SSD accomplishes this by simply mapping a different physical location to those LBA blocks.

At the NAND level we now have two copies of your file, the original in a location no longer mapped to any LBA address, we call this stale data, and the new file (the shredded variant).

**So, all we need is a tool that allows us to access the data that's outside the 'LBA domain'.**

Option 1:

PC3000 SSD by Acelab. Almost every data recovery lab has this tool. To access your 'stale data' it is required though that the tool 'knows' the SSD model. Even if a specific model is not supported at this point, it may be in the future. New models are added constantly.

See: https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2019/01/life-after-trim-using-factory-access-mode-for-imaging-ssd-drives/

Option 2:

Dump the NAND and bypass controller altogether.

Example: http://www.flash-extractor.com/library/SSD/IDX110M00/IDX100M01-LC%20v2__2c_68_04_46__16x1

On modern NAND this impossible though as although we can read the NAND, the data is encrypted and can (at this point) not be decrypted since we lack assistance of the controller.

Example: http://www.flash-extractor.com/library/SSD/SandForce/SF-2281VB1-SDC-S03__2c_88_04_4b__4x4

With regards to SMR drives, the most recent update (at day of writing this) of PC3000 further enhances support for such drives: https://youtu.be/PylbEVGWo3M

Comment: From the citation: "This study has demonstrated that correctly wiped data cannot reasonably be retrieved" – If data can be retrieved, can we ever call it *correctly* wiped? :)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski lol. "I was able to recover this wiped data" .. "Well okay, it wasn't wiped correctly then" ..

Comment: Great area for circular reasoning or some similar fallacy, I guess.

Comment: Re "Can not be recovered, now!", it should be noted that current hard drives operate at the limits of quantum mechanics (single magnetic domains). The historical argument was based on the observation that an overwrite might not overwrite all magnetic domains, back in the days when a single bit spanned many domains. HDD development tries to shrink these magnetic domains, but for a given disk this size is fixed. No future research can change this; randomly flipping each magnetic domain is therefore safe.

Comment: @MSalters, agreed. I was kinda playing Devil's advocate.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski “Correctly wiped” _is_ meaningful in this context. It means that the part(s) of the disk containing the data have actually been overwritten. As opposed to, for example, running `shred`, but due to either the filesystem design or the storage technology or both, that overwrote a different part of the physical storage, not where the sensitive data was and still is stored.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to look at different levels of security.

1. You are having user rights. Them a simple `rm` will be enough. Take care of other copies, e.g., in backups and filesystem accessible snapshots.
2. You have root privileges. Then you may access any snapshots and any raw data on the disk. On some filesystems shred will work, on others not. Especially COW filesystems like btrfs, ZFS and nilfs2 are a problem. ext3/4 in journal write-back mode is also a problem.
3. You're hacking the drive's firmware. Then you may have the possiblity to access remapped blocks and wear-leveling blocks. There may be alternative firmwares that make it easy and there may be homebrew firmwares or raw-access modes for that. This will especially allow to access spare blocks on SSDs.
4. You're accessing the drive on hardware level. Then you can, for example, try to read bad blocks, that cannot even be read with a firmware that ignores the block being marked as bad because they are actually bad. If the blocks are indeed defect (and not only hard to read) they are almost impossible to restore on modern drives. In the past there were methods reading blocks with more expensive equipment, but with drives getting more and more storage with increasing complex methods most of these methods won't work anymore. If someone tells you to wipe 35 times, they are talking about 100 megabyte drives and not 10 terabyte drives.

The most common threat model would be a root-level access. And there you have to deal with the filesystem features. I'd recommend encrypting the drive and preventing people from getting root access on the running system. Then you're fine in most scenarios. Encryption will also prevent problems in the more sophisticated scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Take your SSD and use various tools to physically "shred" the device. Hammers, angle grinders etc are useful.

Then chuck the fragments in the nearest river.